# How to allow anonymous access to a shared directory?

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

I have Ubuntu 22.04 in Windows domain LAN.
My idea is: to create a shared folder which is accessible for any users from Windows without name/pwd dialogs.
I have installed Samba server, created a folder and made it Local network share.
It displayed with an icon etc. OK.
Then

1. I try to open in in Windows :
   In File explorer: \192.168.0.17 I do not see this folder
2. I try to open it on the same machine (Ubuntu) where it located: open Files, then smb://192.168.0.17/storage2 -> Connect
   Unable to access location

What I have missed? How to fix it and make this shared directory accessible to any anonymous users from Windows machines?

Comment: You probably meant guest access, because samba isn't anonymous.

Comment: Insufficient information provided to answer the question. Please edit your original post and add the output of the following commands: `testparm -s` ... `net usershare info --long` ... And that version of Windows are you using?

Comment: It is Windows 10

Comment: I asked for 3 pieces of information. You gave me one.